# Actualizar atributos dentro de un subdocumento array de otro subdocumento array en mongoDB teniendo los ids únicos para cada subdocumento

Tags: mongodb

Tengo el siguiente collection.

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5",
      "usuarioId":"usuario 1",
      "perfiles":[
         {
            "_id":"5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7",
            "perfil":"perfil 1",
            "estudios":[
               {
                  "_id":"5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731",
                  "institucion":"institucion 1"
               },
               {
                  "_id":"5c9980eb02d0a920bcb66db3",
                  "institucion":"institucion 2"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Deseo actualizar el atributo institución pero no logro hacerlo a pesar de que cada objeto tiene un id único.

He intentado con:

```
db.collection.update(
      { 
        "_id": ObjectId("5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5"), 
        "perfiles._id": ObjectId("5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7"), 
        "perfiles.estudios._id": ObjectId("5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731") },
      { 
        $set : { "perfiles.$.estudios.$.institucion" : "institucion 3" } 
      }
    ) // Sale error
```

o

```
db.collection.update(
  { 
    "_id": ObjectId("5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5"), 
    "perfiles._id": ObjectId("5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7"), 
    "perfiles.estudios._id": ObjectId("5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731") },
  { 
    $set : { "perfiles.[]$.estudios.$.institucion" : "institucion 3" } 
  }
) // Me actualiza el que no es
```

Alguna idea? De antemano muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para realizar la actualización que deseas debes usar filtros pasados en la opción `arrayFilters`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar un campo de un documento anidado en una colección de MongoDB, usando como filtros los campos `_id` de los documentos anidados.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la tarea debemos crear un `array` con los filtros que queremos usar en nuestra actualización.

La colección tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
[
    {
        "_id":"5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5",
        "usuarioId":"usuario 1",
        "perfiles":[
            {
                "_id":"5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7",
                "perfil":"perfil 1",
                "estudios":[
                    {
                        "_id":"5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731",
                        "institucion":"institucion 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "_id":"5c9980eb02d0a920bcb66db3",
                        "institucion":"institucion 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Notemos lo siguiente de los documentos anidados:

**`perfiles`**: Este es un campo tipo `array`, y pertenece a un documento de la colección. Los elementos de este `array` son documentos.

**`estudios`**: Este es un campo tipo `array`, y pertenece a un documento del campo `perfiles` de la colección. Los elementos de este `array` también son documentos.

Cada documento de `perfiles` contiene un campo `_id` y cada documento de `estudios` también contiene su respectivo campo `_id`.

Vamos a actualizar el campo `institución` que pertenece a un documento tipo `estudios`. El documento que vamos a actualizar tiene el campo `_id` igual a `"5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731"`

El documento tipo `estudios` pertenece al documento tipo `perfiles` con `_id` igual a `"5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7"`.

Como el documento que deseamos actualizar pertenece a un `array`, debemos usar un filtro que pasaremos dentro de `arrayFilters`. Este filtro indicará el documento anidado que deseamos actualizar.

El método [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) acepta tres parámetros: `(query,  update, options)`

**`query`**: Será la consulta para indicarle a Mongo el documento de la colección que deseamos actualizar. En este caso será la siguiente: **`{"_id": ObjectId("5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5")}`**

**`update`**: Aquí indicamos la actualización que vamos a realizar. Como queremos actualizar un documento anidado que pertenece a un `array`, que a su vez pertenece a un documento anidado en otro `array`, y por el hecho de tener más de un documento en cada `array`, no podemos realizar una actualización directa. Debemos usar un operador de filtrado posicional [`$[<identificador>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]). Debido a que tenemos 2 documentos anidados, haremos uso de 2 filtros. Así, nuestro parámetro queda de la siguiente forma: **`{$set: {"perfiles.$[perf].estudios.$[est].institucion": "Escola Poblenou"}}`**, donde `"Escola Poblenou"` es el valor a actualizar.

Analicemos esto: `"perfiles.$[perf].estudios.$[est].institucion`. Hemos usado 2 identificadores de posición, a uno lo he llamado `perf` y al otro lo he llamado `est`, solo para tener una coherencia. El nombre no importa (aunque deben ser diferentes entre si), y será el mismo que usaremos en nuestra opción `arrayFilters`. El primer identificador hace referencia a un elemento de `perfiles` que concuerde con nuestro filtro. El segundo identificador hace referencia a un elemento de `estudios` que concuerde con nuestro filtro. Digo "elemento" porque estamos hablando de `arrays`.

**`options`**: Aquí pasaremos la opción `arrayFilters`, la cual va a contener los filtros que queremos se apliquen a nuestros identificadores. Como en este caso queremos un filtrar mediante el campo `_id` de cada documento anidado, entonces lso filtros quedarán de la siguiente forma: **`{arrayFilters:[{"perf._id": {$eq: ObjectId("5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7")}},{"est._id":{$eq: ObjectId("5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731")}}]}`**

Analicemos esto un poco. `arrayFilters` es un `array` (que sorpresa), que contiene los siguientes filtros:

`{"perf._id": {$eq: ObjectId("5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7")}}`: Este filtro selecciona un elemento de `perfiles` cuyo `_id` coincida con el que hemos pasado.

`{"est._id": {$eq: ObjectId("5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731")}}`: Este filtro selecciona un elemento de `estudios` cuyo `_id` coincida con el que hemos pasado.

Notemos que hemos usado el nombre del identificador que creamos en nuestro parámetro update. Esto es simplemente elegante.

Por último la instrucción completa queda de la siguiente manera:

```
db.collection.update({"_id": {$eq: ObjectId("5c3d2b3502d0a9467037ede5")}},{$set: {"perfiles.$[perf].estudios.$[est].institucion": "Escola Poblenou"}},{arrayFilters:[{"perf._id": {$eq: ObjectId("5c3d2b4702d0a9467037ede7")}},{"est._id":{$eq: ObjectId("5c5110da02d0a90ba0926731")}}]})
```

Recuerda cambiar el nombre de la colección en `db.collection`.

Espero que sea la respuesta que estabas buscando.

Puedes encontrar algunos ejemplos de uso de `arrayFilters` en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-arrayfilters) de Mongo.

Comment: +1, Wooooo Mauricio esta respuesta vale oro, eres el mejor, funciona perfecto, gracias.